# Target only bar buttons of the top navigation bar using the appearance proxy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I am using the appearance proxy to style my app, but I have a problem with the [UIBarButtonItem appearance]; I want to only style the buttons of the top UINavigationbar, but when I run the code below, the same style also gets applied to the done button of the keyboard.

```
NSDictionary *btnAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [UIColor blackColor],
                              UITextAttributeTextColor,
                              [UIColor clearColor],
                              UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: btnAttributes
                                            forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image: The style gets applied to the keyboards done button]

So, my question is: Is it possible - using the appearance proxy - to style only bar buttons of the top navigation bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can restrict the appearance to certain container classes. From the [appearance reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

```
appearanceWhenContainedIn:
```

> Returns the appearance proxy for the receiver in a given containment
>   hierarchy. (required)

```
+ (id)appearanceWhenContainedIn:(Class <UIAppearanceContainer>)ContainerClass,...
```

***Parameters***
ContainerClass, 
A nil-terminated list of appearance container classes.
Return Value
The appearance proxy for the receiver in a given containment hierarchy.

***Discussion***
This method throws an exception for any item in the var-args list that is not a Class object that conforms to the UIAppearanceContainer protocol.

Availability
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

---

For your example, that would be:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil]
                     setTitleTextAttributes:btnAttributes
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Be careful when using classes like `MPMoviePlayerController` as that beast actually uses a subclass of `UINavigationController` but is not appearance compliant. Anyways, glad I could be of help.